# Get the Image as a byte and send to Facebook Api

Tags: c#

I need to send an image as a Byte Array to facebook API. I try to get the file from my Mac and send it but it is breaking in second line when it is reading file.

```
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(request.PhotoUrl);
        byte[] photoContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

I am using Mac, so my path is looks like:

```
  "photoUrl": "/Users/myname/Documents/test.png"
```

It is bringing fileName is but braking in second line.

Comment: **How** is it breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path.GetFileName() should be returning the filename and its extension.  So in your case, fileName will be set to test.png  Therefore when you try to read the file your call to File.ReadAllBytes(fileName) will fail unless you are running the program from the same folder as the picture file.  Instead of using Path.GetFileName() you could use Path.GetFullPath() or even just pass the PhotoUrl value to the ReadAllBytes function.

Microsoft documentation for

- GetFullPath(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1
- GetFileName():  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netcore-3.1